# SparkR to output multiple files per key

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I have been working on a project in SparkR.I have a flatmap of values which contains dataframes . When i save the flatmap  results to text file, it gives me a single text file. I want to get each file per key in flatmap in the result.How do I achieve this??

Adjust calculations for each key obtained from the group

```
dfsMapKey<-SparkR:::flatMap(dfsGroupKey,function(current_key)
   {
  tryCatch({
 data<-as.data.frame(t(sapply(current_key[[2]], rbind))) # current_key[[1]] as key and current_key[[2]] as list of values for each key
 names(data)<-names(current_key[[2]][[1]]) 
 data<-format_data_type(data)
 current_parameter <- matrix(
     list(as.character(unique(data$x)),unique(as.character(data$y)),data_year), # the columns for the field , which yield has to be adjusted
      nrow=1,              # number of rows
      ncol=3,              # number of columns
      byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows
     dimnames(current_parameter) = list(
      list("current_field"),         # row names
      list("x","y","data_year")) #colnames
 fields<<-as.data.frame(current_parameter["current_field",])
 print(fields)
 data<-clean_data(data)
 data$field <- as.character(data$field)
 data <- seperate_combined_fields(data)
 data <- data[ , !(names(data) %in% c("gps_year", "gps_month", "gps_day", "crop"))]
 approach <<- "gam" # enter "gam" or "loess"
 useSpan <<- 0.015
 nbs <<- 500 # number of basic splines
 data <- adjust_values(data)
 data <- data[ , !(names(data) %in% c("x"))]
 data[is.na(data)] <- ''
 data[data == "NA" ] <-''
 data <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(data, rbind)))
 return(data)
  }, error=function(e){
    print(e)
  })
})
 SparkR:::saveAsTextFile( dfsMapKey , "yieldTesting")
```

Comment: Could you share the code sample?

Comment: Added the code above.Also while saving the text file. all the data is preceded with a space in front of it.like 1, 2, 3 etc. Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Not sure whether the following steps will solve your problems or not but, in such scenarios I prefer to use repartition by the key and use dapply to do the stuff I want